# What could be the cause of PC crashing then failing to reboot for a while?

Tags: windows-10, crash

When running certain games my pc will reliably crash to complete black after few minutes. After that, it will attempt to boot a couple of times but go to black again during boot before completing.

All the temperatures I could monitor are fine. I think all the drivers are up to date and the problem persisted over reinstalling windows.
Also this machine ran perfectly before.

Now I dont have replacement parts to try and figure out which component might be faulty.

By these symptoms can someone guess whats the problem? Or have advice to narrow it down?

Edit:
Crash happens when running FurMark but not with Prime95. But also the GPU has 3 times the TDP of my CPU.

Windows System logs show a "Critical Kernel-Power 41" before the crash.

Comment: Run hardware diagnostics for all the components and see if any component surfaces as a problem.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Open Event Viewer, look under Windows logs. What errors system log shows just before crash? Only the red real errors are important at start, not the warnings denoted by yellow triangles.

Comment: Sounds like it may be a faulty PSU. Have you got another to test with?